# svg rect pattern overlapping issue

Tags: css, svg

Let's say 2 svg rect with pattern stripes are overlapping each other. Is there anyway, svg with darker pattern fill should be visible in overlapping area.

```css
svg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern-stripe" 
      width="4" height="4" 
      patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      patternTransform="rotate(135)">
      <rect width="2" height="4" transform="translate(0,0)" fill="white"></rect>
    </pattern>
    <mask id="mask-stripe">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-stripe)" />
    </mask>      
  </defs>
  <!-- horizontal bar chart -->
  <rect mask=url(#mask-stripe) x="30" y="20" width="123" height="50" fill="#b3b3b3"></rect>
  <rect mask=url(#mask-stripe) x="0" y="20" width="100" height="50" fill="black"></rect>
</svg>
```

Please let me know if there is any possibility?

Comment: The darker pattern is already the one that's visible in the overlapping area (at least on desktop Firefox and Chrome). What is the problem?

Comment: calculate the 4 coordinates where the ``<rect>`` overlap; then draw another RECT